# How to give PdfReader a HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

As I see itextsharp's PdfReader object accepts a filename. But I have HttpPostedFileBase in my controller, how can I give HttpPostedFileBase to PdfReader. Here is the code :

```
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        PdfReader myReader = new PdfReader(file); // this gives error.
```

Comment: Error details please?

Comment: Error is PdfReader accepts string not HttpPostedFileBase

Comment: Your comment is incomplete. `PdfReader` also accepts a `byte[]`, `InputStream`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `HttpPostedFileBase` named `file`, then you could do this:

```
byte[] pdfbytes = null;
BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
pdfbytes = rdr.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfbytes);
```

You could, of course, first save the PDF to a file, and then provide the path to that file, but usually, that's not what you want.

Comment: How can I do what you said? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Didn't I just provide the source code?